# unable to retrieve record from MySQL using UUID with springboot jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, jdbc

I am using uuid as id for the MySQL db. But when I try to retrieve using id, it's returning null rather than the correct object. I crossed check the db using workbench, the record is there but its not retrieving when trying to do usig JPA. I have following classes

BaseEntity:

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    UUID id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    Date createdAt;
}
```

ArticleRepo:

```
@Repository
public interface ArticlesRepository extends JpaRepository<ArticleEntity, UUID> {
    ArticleEntity findBySlug(String slug);
    Optional<ArticleEntity> findById(UUID id);
}
```

ArticleService:

```
@Service
public class ArticlesService {

    public final ArticlesRepository articlesRepository;
    public final UsersRepository usersRepository;

    public ArticlesService(
            ArticlesRepository articlesRepository,
            UsersRepository usersRepository
    ) {
        this.articlesRepository = articlesRepository;
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }

    public List<ArticleEntity> getAllArticles(){
        List<ArticleEntity> articlesIterable = articlesRepository.findAll();
        return StreamSupport.stream(articlesIterable.spliterator(),false)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public ArticleEntity getArticleBySlug(String slug){
        var article = articlesRepository.findBySlug(slug);
        if(slug==null){
            return null;
        }
        return article;
    }

    public ArticleEntity createArticle(CreateArticleDTO createArticleDTO, String authorUsername){
        var author = usersRepository.findByUsername(authorUsername);
        return articlesRepository.save(
                ArticleEntity.builder()
                        .title(createArticleDTO.getTitle())
                        .slug(createArticleDTO.getTitle().toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","-"))
                        .subtitle(createArticleDTO.getSubtitle())
                        .body(createArticleDTO.getBody())
                        .author(author)
                        .build()
                );
    }

    public Optional<ArticleEntity> getArticleById(UUID id){
        return articlesRepository.findById(id);
    }
}

Whenever I try to get a record using the UUID, I am getting null as opposed to the record.
```

Tried to store the UUID AS VARCHAR in MySQL db, that didnt work either:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.BINARY)
    UUID id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    Date createdAt;
}
```

Comment: Can you add **ArticleEntity** code?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

1. Define the Id as following in the abstract class:
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
   private String id;
2. I believe ArticleEntity should extend the base BaseEntity class.
3. Try calling repository.findById(String id), providing the id as a parameter. You don't need to define this method again in your repository interface, as it would be already there in JpaRepository.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).